# .htacces - Redirect all requests to a certain directory, except for direct url access

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I have a forum and a website which were located in / (root) and /website/. Now, I moved my forum to /forum/ in order to organize the web server better and to be actually able to find something when needed.

What I want to do is somehow redirect requests like

```
www.mywebsite.com    
http://mywebsite.com/
http://www.mywebsite.com/
```

to `/website/` and any request made to my base url but followed by a page (`www.mywebsite.com/index.php` as an example) to my `/forum` subfolder.

Is that even possible to do en-mase ? Or can I least redirect if I match a specific file ?

Rule that redirects requests to base url over to my website folder that I have in my .htacces already.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.domain.com$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "http\:\/\/www.domain\.com\/website_folder\/" [R=301,L]
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^/?$ /website_root/ [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^((?!(?:website_root|forum)/).+)$ /forum/$1 [L,NC]
```

Comment: That doesn't really work since I need something more specific.

Comment: Accessing `mywebsite.com` redirects to my website directory accordingly (since I have another rule for this already) but accesing something like `mywebsite.com/viewtopic.php?t=450` still gives an error since it's not getting redirected to `mywebsite.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=450`

I think you didn't read everything in my post.

Comment: Basically when someone enters `mywebsite.com/any_page.extension` to be redirected to `mywebsite.com/forum/any_page.extension` I worte an example there. Check main for .htaccess (it's just the code snippet that's important).

Comment: They are the same, it's just a placeholder.  Damn, so, let me try to explain again. We use `mywebsite.com` as a reference to my website.  

We have 2 cases:  
1)  Someone tries to access `mywebsite.com` (or with www/http and whatnot, you get the point). When that happens, I want to redirect him to `mywebsite.com/website_root/`. Where `website_root` is the folder that contains my website.  
2) Someone tries to acces `mywebsite.com/index.php` (or any other file). I want to redirect him to `mywebsite.com/forum/index.php`. Where `forum` is the folder that contains my forum.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73833/discussion-between-anubhava-and-shao2k).